# Show viewcontroller on receive of push notification is not working, whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, push-notification

My AppDelegate is in objective c and the viewcontroller i want to show on receive of push notification is in Swift. I tried many things but i am not able to get the correct view controller on receive of the push notification. Below is the code what i tried -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *sessionUserID = [defaults objectForKey:@"USERID"];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

NSLog(@"App State Inactive->%d",application.applicationState== UIApplicationStateInactive);
NSLog(@"App State Active->%d",application.applicationState== UIApplicationStateActive);
NSLog(@"App State Active->%d",application.applicationState== UIApplicationStateBackground);

NSLog(@"=====userinfo %@",userInfo);
NSString *msgID  = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];
    if(sessionUserID != nil){
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *destCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notification"]; // Swift viewcontroller
        UIViewController *navController =(UIViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
        [navController presentViewController:destCon animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Below is the log message -

```
2015-10-19 18:40:43.363 VidurOnMobile[631:94551] App State Inactive->1
2015-10-19 18:40:43.363 VidurOnMobile[631:94551] App State Active->0
2015-10-19 18:40:43.363 VidurOnMobile[631:94551] App State Active->0
2015-10-19 18:40:43.364 VidurOnMobile[631:94551] =====userinfo {
    aps =     {
        alert = test;
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
    id = 1;
}
2015-10-19 18:40:43.364 VidurOnMobile[631:94551] Session is still there
2015-10-19 18:40:43.646 VidurOnMobile[631:94551] Warning: Attempt to present <VidurOnMobile.NotificationDetails: 0x156c5810> on <VidurOnMobile.LoginViewController: 0x15553910> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Please Help, I tried many thing but its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *destCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notification"]; // Swift viewcontroller
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

UIViewController *activeController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

if ([activeController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
   activeController = [(UINavigationController*) activeController visibleViewController];
}

[activeController presentViewController:destCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: 2015-10-19 18:57:54.358 VidurOnMobile[653:99800] Warning: Attempt to present <VidurOnMobile.NotificationDetails: 0x16d81000> on <VidurOnMobile.LoginViewController: 0x16ea5650> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: You can actually present a modal view Controller from the `AppDelegate` as long as you detect the current visible viewController. Can you please try with my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `sessionUserID` is not nil?
Then get the top view controller of the navigation controller and present the notification view controller. Try this

```
   UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
   UIViewController *topViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
   UIViewController *destCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notification"]; // Swift viewcontroller
   [topViewController presentModalViewController:destCon animated:YES];
```

Comment: App is crashing with this code - below is the log message

Comment: 2015-10-20 14:30:56.485 VidurOnMobile[1155:235398] -[VidurOnMobile.LoginViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166773d0
2015-10-20 14:30:56.488 VidurOnMobile[1155:235398] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VidurOnMobile.LoginViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166773d0'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue -

```
UIViewController *main=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];

        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];
        self.window.rootViewController =nil;
        UIViewController *destCon = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notification"];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:destCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```